# How to tag a dequeueReusableCell without mess the content?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have used a `dequeueReusableCell` in a list, and there are 4 UILabel in the cell. There are screenshots below.

Whichever the label has a prefix of "-", it will be Red, but after scroll it a few pages, the number has become a mess. Wonder if there a way to avoid this?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecipeTableCell", for: indexPath)
    let currentRecipe = recipes?[indexPath.row]
    let colorRed = UIColor(red: 0xFE/255, green: 0x38/255, blue: 0x24/255, alpha: 1) //FE3824

    (cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView).image = UIImage(named: currentRecipe?.pic ?? "")
    (cell.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel).text = currentRecipe?.name

    let hungryLabel = cell.viewWithTag(301) as! UILabel
    hungryLabel.text = currentRecipe?.hungry_value
    if (currentRecipe?.hungry_value!.hasPrefix("-"))! {
        hungryLabel.textColor = colorRed
    }

    let healthLabel = (cell.viewWithTag(302) as! UILabel)
    healthLabel.text = currentRecipe?.health_value
    if (currentRecipe?.health_value!.hasPrefix("-"))! {
        healthLabel.textColor = colorRed
    }

    let sanityLabel = (cell.viewWithTag(303) as! UILabel)
    sanityLabel.text = currentRecipe?.sanity_value
    if (currentRecipe?.sanity_value!.hasPrefix("-"))! {
        sanityLabel.textColor = colorRed
    }

    (cell.viewWithTag(304) as! UILabel).text = currentRecipe?.duration

    return cell
}
```

[image: Shot Before Scroll]

[image: Shot After scroll]

---

## Thanks you guys.

> I add a Black Color to 'else', it works, thank you

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecipeTableCell", for: indexPath)
    let currentRecipe = recipes?[indexPath.row]
    let colorRed = UIColor(red: 0xFE/255, green: 0x38/255, blue: 0x24/255, alpha: 1)    //FE3824
    let colorBlack = UIColor(red: 74/255, green: 74/255, blue: 74/255, alpha: 1)        //747474

    (cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView).image = UIImage(named: currentRecipe?.pic ?? "")
    (cell.viewWithTag(200) as! UILabel).text = currentRecipe?.name

    let hungryLabel = cell.viewWithTag(301) as! UILabel
    hungryLabel.text = currentRecipe?.hungry_value
    if (currentRecipe?.hungry_value!.hasPrefix("-"))! {
        hungryLabel.textColor = colorRed
    } else {
        hungryLabel.textColor = colorBlack
    }

    let healthLabel = (cell.viewWithTag(302) as! UILabel)
    healthLabel.text = currentRecipe?.health_value
    if (currentRecipe?.health_value!.hasPrefix("-"))! {
        healthLabel.textColor = colorRed
    } else {
        healthLabel.textColor = colorBlack
    }

    let sanityLabel = (cell.viewWithTag(303) as! UILabel)
    sanityLabel.text = currentRecipe?.sanity_value
    if (currentRecipe?.sanity_value!.hasPrefix("-"))! {
        sanityLabel.textColor = colorRed
    } else {
        sanityLabel.textColor = colorBlack
    }

    (cell.viewWithTag(304) as! UILabel).text = currentRecipe?.duration

    return cell
}
```

[image: Works now]

Comment: [Edit] your question with your `cellForRowAt` method.

Comment: Show us your code from where you managed Label's color based on prefix '-'.

Comment: Cells are reused. In `cellForRow` add an `else` clause to explicitly set the color to black if the value is **not** negative.

Comment: @vadian Thanks It helps

Comment: PS: `viewWithTag` is very old-fashioned. Design a **custom** cell in IB and use outlets. And for gray-scale colors there is a convenient initializer `let colorBlack = UIColor(white: 74/255, alpha: 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your cellForRowAt method you need to check if value is positive the color is black and if negative the it is red. For example

```
label.color = black

if negativeValue {
     lagel.color = red
}
```